# PHP Detect if any URL variables have been set

Tags: php

I have a webpage to which any amount of URL varibales could be set.. examples:

- index.php?source=lol
- index.php?source=lol&sub=haha
- index.php?aff=123
- index.php?keyword=pizza

I want a way that I can detect that any url variable has been set, if a url variable has been set I want to print something on the page. Any ideas? I couldn't find anything on Google about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`count($_GET);` will return the number of parameters in the URL.  Use `if (count($_GET) > 0)` to test for their presence.

For example:

```
if (count($_GET) > 0){
    print "You supplied values!";
} else {
    print "Please supply some values.";
}
```

Comment: +1. Now that I re-read the OP's question 3 times, I *think* this is what he is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Check isset($_GET['var_name'])

http://php.net/isset

Comment: ... in conjunction with $_GET or $_REQUEST, which contain the URL variables. If you want to process them further, be sure to inform yourself about how to handle user input securely.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if a variable has been set using [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) or [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists):

```
if (isset($_GET['source']))
    doSomething();
```

You can loop over all the querystring variable like this:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
    echo htmlspecialchars($key) . ' is set to ' . htmlspecialchars($value);
```

Comment: Don't you think that var_dump($_GET) or print_r($_GET) more useful than foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

More general:

```
if (count($_GET)) {
 foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  echo "Key $key has been set to $value<br />\n";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if any variables has been sent, use the function below.

```
function hasGet()
{
    return !empty($_GET);
}

if (hasGet()) {
    echo "something on the page";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since $_GET returns an array, it might be safer to check its size using sizeof() function

Example:

```
 if(sizeof($_GET)>0){
   /*you had passed something on your link*/
 }else{
   /*you did not passed anything on your link*/
 }
```